# Select random item from 1d array no repeat

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select random item from 1d array using this code

```
Sub Select_Random_Item_From_1D_Array()
    Dim arr(), x As Long
    arr = Array("Good", "Very Good", "Excellent")
    Randomize
    x = Int((UBound(arr) + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    Debug.Print arr(x - 1)
End Sub
```

How can I be able to prevent a repetition? I mean I need to select all the items randomly with no repetition. And if all the items are selected then to reset the process. Simply I need to select all the items randomly

Comment: You could create a second array, having the same length, having only 1 and 0. First initialize the second array with only 0s. If a value from your array is selected by the rand, then set the second array matching value to 1. And if the rand value next time is on a value which has already been selected (with a 1 in the second array), do the rand again

Comment: This is a pretty stupid solution but I think it does the job?

Comment: Can you show me please to learn something new?

Comment: I'll write a little example

Comment: "if all the items are selected then to reset the process" - do you mean reshuffle the array, or just start again at the beginning of the already-shuffled array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple way to return a random permutation of an array that takes exactly `n` steps, where `n` is the number of entries in the array.

```
 Dim arr(), x As Long, r As Long
    arr = Array("Good", "Very Good", "Excellent")
    x = UBound(arr)
    While x >= 0
    r = Int(Rnd * x)
    Debug.Print arr(r)
    arr(r) = arr(x)
    x = x - 1
    Wend
```

Pick `r` at random from (0,..,x) and print out `arr(r)`. Then replace the entry at `r` with the entry at `x`, and choose again, but this time from (0,..,x-1), and repeat until `x=0`.

A fuller version that lets you read one entry at a time is here:

Place this in a module:

```
Public rarr(), ctr As Integer, arr()

Sub init()
    With Cells
        .Clear
        .ColumnWidth = 10
    End With
    Dim x As Long, r As Long
    arr = Array("Very Poor", "Poor", "Average", "Good", "Very Good", "Excellent")
    x = UBound(arr)
    ReDim rarr(0 To x)
    Randomize
    While x >= 0
    r = Int(Rnd * x)
    rarr(x) = arr(r)
    arr(r) = arr(x)
    x = x - 1
    Wend
    [a1:f1] = rarr
    ctr = 0
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click()
Cells(ctr + 3, 1) = rarr(ctr)
ctr = ctr + 1
If ctr > UBound(rarr) Then init
End Sub
```

and add two buttons to the worksheet. Point one at `init` and the other at `Button1_Click`. Click `init` first, and then pressing `Button1` displays a random and unique entry one at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much. The same note ( when I run the code I need to select only one item my bro) and the second time when to run the code again need to pick another different item and so on.

Comment: Store the random array in a new array, and then just read these off one at a time.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. Storing the random new array would not result in what I am seeking to. Simply, I will run the code several times, each time I need to print a unique item till the items finished. When all the items selected then I need to reset the process.

Comment: Make a random array once at the start of the code, like shuffling a pack of cards. Then every time you need a new card, read the next item from the array. If you mean to store the array over several sessions, you will need to store the array as a file somewhere.

Comment: I am really confused. Can you add to your answer an example?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a second array of `Booleans`, having the same length.
This array is initialized with only `False`. If a value from your array is selected by the rand, then set the boolean array matching value to `True`. And if the rand value next time is on a value which has already been selected (with a `True` in the boolean array), do the rand again

Try this little example step by step, you'll see the logic:

```
Sub Select_Random_Item_From_1D_Array()
    Dim arr(), x As Long, cpt As Long
    Dim mBool(2) As Boolean
    cpt = 0
    arr = Array("Good", "Very Good", "Excellent")
    Do While cpt < 3 '3 being the number of items in your array + 1 (from 0 to 2)
        Randomize
        x = Int((UBound(arr) + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        If mBool(x - 1) = False Then
            mBool(x - 1) = True
            Debug.Print arr(x - 1)
            cpt = cpt + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

It will print a random item from your array, and every time it does so it changes the matching value of the 2nd array from `False` to `True`. Then it does it again and if it has already been printed (if the matching value on the boolean array is `True`) it tries again.

I added a variable named `cpt`, which goes from 0 to the number of items in your array, it makes the algorithm stop when it has printed all the items one time.

This is probably not he best way to do what you want, but it works and it's not that complicated

Comment: Thanks a lot for great effort. I didn't mean to select all the items my bro. I am sorry for confusion. I meant when I run the code, I expect to print just one item then if I run the code again to print another different item and so one till all the items are selected and printed. At this point, the code would reset the process and start new session,

Comment: This would take a very long time if the array was say 10,000 items.

Comment: @YasserKhalil why not using a static array? It would preserve its value after the code has ended. So next time you run it, it isn't reseted.

Comment: @JMP yeah it would, maybe another way would be to create a second array and each time the rand picks one value you remove the item from this array, so you always look in an array with no value already picked

Comment: The target of the post is to pick only one item when running the code ..!! I feel lost and I am away of my target my bro.

Answer (score 0):

### Select Random Item Series

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Sub resetRandomItem()
    getRandomItem
End Sub

Sub selectRandomItem()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array("Bad", "Better", "Good", "Very Good", "Excellent")
    Debug.Print getRandomItem(arr)
End Sub

' If x elements in 1D array, it returns a series of x different values.
Function getRandomItem(Optional Data1D As Variant) As Variant
    
    Static arr As Variant
    
    ' Reset 'arr': use 'getRandomItem' without 'Data1D' parameter.
    If IsMissing(Data1D) Then arr = Empty: Exit Function
    
    If IsEmpty(arr) Then arr = Data1D
    
    Dim lb As Long: lb = LBound(arr)
    Dim ub As Long: ub = UBound(arr)
    
    If lb = ub Then
        getRandomItem = arr(lb)
        arr = Empty
    Else
        Randomize
        Dim x As Long: x = Int((ub - lb + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        Dim y As Long: y = x + lb - 1
        getRandomItem = arr(y)
        arr(y) = Empty
        
        Dim i As Long, k As Long
        For i = lb To ub - 1
            If arr(i) = Empty Then
                For k = i + 1 To ub
                    arr(k - 1) = arr(k)
                Next k
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        ReDim Preserve arr(ub - 1)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice solution.